# Best Rails 3 XML parser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

Which XML library, GEM would you recommend to use with Rails 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) is widely used.

Comment: No worries, it happens all the time to me :P

Answer (score 1):

Try [hpricot](https://github.com/hpricot/hpricot)!

EDIT: I take that back, hpricot is primarily HTML. [Nokogiri](https://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri) is probably the best option out there today. For a guide, check out this [Engine Yard blog post](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/getting-started-with-nokogiri/).